# Haskell: cannot construct the infinite type

Tags: haskell

I got a list of tuples (day:month) and want to find the month with the biggest amount of days.

I made a function that accepts my list of tuples and list of months (or just 1) to check and returns the maximum amount of dates in one month in specified period

```
maxweekends x [] = 0
maxweekends x [n] = length (filter ((==n).snd) x)
maxweekends x (y:ys) = max (maxweekends x [y]) (maxweekends x ys)
```

Then I wrote some simple function to use it, but I cant compile it because of "cannot construct the infinite type" error. I already spent a few hours with this error but I just cant understand what is wrong.

```
func x [] = 0
func x (y:ys)
    | maxweekends x y < maxweekends x ys = func x ys
    | otherwise =  y
```

In theory it should call itself until there is no month with bigger amount of dates and then just return answer.

Thanks.

Edit: [here is traceback of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4pw1.png)

Comment: Post the *full* traceback?

Comment: As a general suggestion, instead of letting GHC infer the type for you, and then report inconsistencies, it's usually better to annotate top-level bindings with explicit types. In that way, when the inferred type does not match the intended one, a type error is raised as early as possible, where it is easier to fix. Indeed, most Haskellers start coding a function by writing its type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your infinite type arises from the fact that you call `maxweekends` with `x y` and `x ys`. Since the type of `maxweekends :: Eq b => [(a, b)] -> [b] -> Int` specifies that given the "second" parameter is of type `[b]`, then the first parameter is a type of `[(a, b)]`, this means that `x` should be `[(a, b)]` (for the first call) and `[(a, [b])]` (for the second call) at the same time, which is impossible.

I think it might be better to first *restructure* this. Let us first construct a function that looks like:

```
groupLength :: Eq b => Int -> b -> [(a, b)] -> Int
groupLength d _ [] = d
groupLength _ x ys = length (filter ((x==) . snd) ys)
```

This will thus for a given "month" `x` obtain the number of elements in the list with as second item of the tuple that "month".

Now we can generate an "argmax" that calculates for which `x`, `f x` produces a maximum value:

```
argmax :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Maybe (a, b)
argmax _ [] = Nothing
argmax f (x:xs) = Just (go x (f x) xs)
    where go x y [] = (x, y)
          go x y (x2:xs) | y <= y2 = go x y xs
                         | otherwise = go x2 y2 xs
              where y2 = f x2
```

So now it is only a matter of combining the the `groupLength` (which is an abstract version of your `maxweekends` with `argmax` (which is more or less what your `func` is after). I leave this as an exercise.